# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/draw2d/LightweightSystem although it is added

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, draw2d

I am trying use draw2d for my plugin development. For now, all I have in my code is:

```
import org.eclipse.draw2d.LightweightSystem;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.*;


public class GraphView extends ViewPart {

public GraphView() {

}
@Override
public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {

    //use LightweightSystem to create the bridge between SWT and draw2D
    final LightweightSystem lws = new LightweightSystem(new Canvas(parent, SWT.NONE));

}

@Override
public void setFocus() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

I get the org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: **java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/draw2d/LightweightSystem** when I launch my eclipse application. I have org.eclipse.draw2d added to my project as an external jar.

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

Adding the jar to the build path only makes your compiler in the IDE finds the classes. For an RCP application you have to add the jar in your `plug-in.xml` as an external jar. Then the jar gets bundled in your application and is available at the runtime of it.

You can do this in the Eclipse editor on the tab `Runtime`. Click `Add...` in the classpath section and add your jar here. This automatically adds the jar to your build path so you might better remove it here before.

You can find a detailed description (with images) here: [Adding a jar file to your Eclipse RCP Plugin](http://www.cyslider.de/blog/index.php/2009/01/06/adding-a-jar-file-to-your-eclipse-rcp-pl)

Comment: Thanks for giving me a hint. Actually, here is the solution I found:

My "required bundle" file in Manifest.mf looked like this when I got the errors:
**Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime**

I changed it to: **Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.draw2d,
 org.csstudio.swt.widgets;bundle-version="2.0.1";resolution:=optional,
 org.csstudio.swt.xygraph;bundle-version="2.0.1";resolution:=optional**

That fixed it!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Putting this as the answer to my question now:

My "required bundle" file in Manifest.mf looked like this when I got the errors:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
                org.eclipse.core.runtime
```

I changed it to:

```
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime,
                org.eclipse.ui,
                org.eclipse.draw2d,
                org.csstudio.swt.widgets;
bundle-version="2.0.1";resolution:=optional, org.csstudio.swt.xygraph;
bundle-version="2.0.1";resolution:=optional**
```